# Как переделать список словарей с одинаковыми ключами в один словарь, в котором в качестве ключей будут те же ключи, а в качестве значений - список

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Прошу помочь.
Есть список словарей:

```
long_term = [{1:-20, 2: 10, 3: 25},
             {1:15, 2: 14, 3: 33},
             {1:8, 2: -2, 3: 16}]
```

Нужно создать словарь:

```
new = {1:[-20, 15, 8]
       2:[10, 14, -2]
       3:[25, 33, 16]}
```

Есть варианты, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from itertools import chain

long_term = [{1:-20, 2: 10, 3: 25},  # Входные данные
             {1:15, 2: 14, 3: 33},
             {1:8, 2: -2, 3: 16}]

new = {}  # Словарь для формирования

for key, value in chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, long_term)):  # Пробегаемся по парам ключ: значение каждого словаря
    new.setdefault(key, []).append(value)  # Если по ключу нет списка, то создаём его, добавляем в список значение
```